# Create Linux installer for .NET Core console app

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a console app which I made using .NET Core. Now I have to create setup for different platform. Using wix I was able to create win32, win64 installer for Windows.

Now I have to create setup for Linux. How can I create setup for Linux platform? I don't want to use Debug or Publish folder. I wanted to give an installer package for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are targeting Linux now, I would recommend to create a `debian` package. For more info, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)

`Debian` packages allow for easy "uninstall", "install" and "upgrade" given that your package is created correctly. You can also run pre and post install shell scripts as part of the package installation.

There's an awesome NuGet package out there that allows you to create debian packages of your .NET core software via the dotnet build command line (I'm personally using it, and it works great). See: https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging